# 2 xinput devices for trackpad

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, xinput

Recently installed Ubuntu 20.4.01 on my dell Inspiron-5390. After booting up everything works fine but if I enter `xinput list` into the terminal, 3 devices appear under "virtual core pointer"
"Virtual core XTEST pointer" and "DELL091F:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad" are expected but "DELL091F:00 27C6:01F0 Mouse" also appears even though this laptop only has a touchpad.

Eveything functions fine after booting the laptop up (input only detected on the touchpad device) but once I suspend the laptop the input device switches to the one labelled "Mouse" and touchpad specific functions stop working.

Does anyone have any idea how I can disable the "mouse" and force Ubuntu to accept inputs from "touchpad" even after suspending.
Below is the output from `xinput list`:

[image]

Raw text of output:\

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  
(3)]\ad
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  
pointer  (2)]\
⎜   ↳ DELL091F:00 27C6:01F0 Mouse               id=10   [slave  
pointer  (2)]\
⎜   ↳ DELL091F:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  
pointer  (2)]\
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard 
(2)]\
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  
keyboard (3)]\ad
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard 
(3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  
keyboard (3)]\
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  
keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text.

Comment: Why did you add `\\` everywhere?

Comment: Hi Sam, I think a screenshot is perfectly in order here, as there's nothing that needs to be copy-pasted. I embedded the image for you using the proper markdown (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I am not sure by what you mean for "touchpad specific functions" though... how can you tell that the "Touchpad" input device stops working?

Comment: @Dagelf Never...never post screenshots of terminal output. It is not OK.

Comment: By touchpad functions i mean things like 2 finger scroll and other gestures specific to touchpads. Also if I run xinput test on both the id's labelled mouse and touchpad the only one that registers any inputs is the touchpad but after the laptop has been suspended and then opened again if I run xinput test on the 2 devices no inputs are registered on the touchpad and instead on the "mouse" even though there is no physical mouse connected and i am still only using the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common with new i2c touchpads. They announce themselves as a touchpad and a mouse for compatibility mode.

In most cases this dosn't cause any trouble. if it does, you can disable the "mouse" in Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad.

If your Desktop Environment doesn't have the option, you can add

```
xinput disable 10
```

command to Startup Applications.

Comment: I can't an option to disable mouse in the setting -> Mouse and Touchpad. The submenu for mouse is there but not the option to disable. Is there somewhere else I can find this?

Comment: Well, GNOME doesn't have it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: After adding this and rebooting the touchpad functions fine but once i suspend the laptop and then turn it back on i can't move the cursor until i re-enable the mouse input. when using xinput --test on both of the "devices" after a reboot inputs are only detected on the touch pad but once i suspend and the reopen the laptop inputs are only detected on the "mouse" device.

Comment: Then this is a bug of suspend feature. Try to update BIOS. If that doesn't help, report a bug. I have a simolar touchpad on two laptops without any issues.

Comment: BTW did you reboot after added the command?

Comment: Yeah i rebooted with that comment in the start up application, eveything was fine until i suspended then I had to turn it back on in the terminal to use the touchpad. BIOS update didn't seem to fix it so I'll just have to report the bug I think

Comment: This approach at least has forced to work a twice-finger touchpad function and a secondary mouse click at the right bottom corner of a touchpad on my dell inspiron 5501. Thnx.